# SP Online rest API datetime-column value inconsistency And how to compare the dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, moment

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/5498c43c-7124-4be5-9627-ea23bd246cba/sharepoint-rest-api-datetime-column-values-inconsistency?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required

Regarding the above thread, i am facing some issue.,while converting the date.

am having a projectenddate and accessing the SP ONLine REST services api, am getting the date -1.

i mean, if the projectenddate is in the record is -- 05/15/2019 then , from the REST API, data.d.results is giving me,

05/14/2019 !!!

how to solve this issue? also i wanna compare this date with todays date.

and if todays date > projectenddate then, i need to delete the item

```
      $.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 

     "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle
         ('Posts_0515_Testing')/items",
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": 
       "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": 
      "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data, 
           textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var items= data.d.results;
                //to do 
              alert('inside data d results');

      for (var i = 0; i < 
      data.d.results.length; i++)   
        {  
            var item = data.d.results[i];  
        var today = new Date();
        var todaysDate = new 
       Date().toISOString();

    alert( "title is--" + item.Title + 
    "====== end date of pub" + 
  item.projectenddate + "<br/>");
```

i wanted to compare the item.projectenddate with Todays Date an if projenddate < todaysdate
then i wanna delete the item

Comment: Usually SP stores dates in UTC, and when you look at them in the browser it is converting them to your local timezone for display. When you retrieve from the REST endpoint you will need to consider whether you need to convert to local time, depending on what you’re doing.

Comment: okay,  i want to convert into local time, its in Europeantime-Fr. Also, how to compare this datetiem field against todays date ? if i use moment.js , will that be okay, ?if yes, any sample code?